# why background image is displaying on half of screen?

Tags: html, css, background-image

My background image is not covering all contents on my page, rather it's applying only half of the screen.

The same code with same image is properly working on my another page.
Only the difference is that i have a lot of content on this page but i think that doesn't matter.

Where is the issue?

Thanks in advance.

html

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<div id="main">
   <!--Here i have multiple sections-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
#main {
   position: relative;
}
#main:before {
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(../..//images/3.jpg) center center fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity : 0.2;
filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    z-index: -1;
```

Comment: Do you want to add background image in the div or the before the div?

Comment: i want to add background image in full of my page or my all contents should be displayed in that image

Comment: Do you mean half the screen, or that you can only see half the image

Comment: So why are you using psudeo operator :before?

Comment: It will not add image before your div element.If you want to apply background image to your page apply it for the body element

Comment: the image is properly displaying but it's covering only half of contents or screen rather than covering full screen.
..
actually i read out this code from google so i copied it from there

Comment: i have tried by defining id="main" in my body too but finding same result

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache so that the new css changes would be reflected

Comment: cache means browser's cache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118505/discussion-between-bhanu-cs-and-bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide).

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Comment: body
{
margin:0px;

width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
#main {
     background-image: url('download.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Answer (score 2):

Hi, you just try with following CSS snippets

```
background: url(../..//images/3.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
```

Comment: background-size: cover; its cover the entire block with image without squeeze; if you can't see the full image, use background-contain.

Answer (score 1):

This method will work

```
  body
{
margin:0px;

width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
#main {
     background-image: url('download.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using a psudeo element :before .The functionality of psudeo element :before is as follows.
  It would attach a child node at the first index.In your case you are trying to attach an image before the div element.And this does not correspond to your whole body.

To make the image applicable to your whole body try this:

```
 body
{
margin:0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url(../..//images/3.jpg) repeat left top;
}
```

And remove your psudeo element :before

```
#main {
   position: relative;
   /*Other CSS Properties*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
background-image: url(path-to-file/img.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: background-image: url(path-to-file/img.jpg);
background-position: center center;
....
I have already these lines of code in my question.
see again

Comment: they are not there

Comment: see this ...  background: url(../..//images/3.jpg) center center fixed;

Comment: sorry. Didn't notice it as greyed out by double slash in the url

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have missed a double quote while writing your ID.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<!--Here i have multiple sections-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no dear, that was missed by mistake...
see my edited code in question